# JS Codecademy Return II - Issue with Return

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having a problem with the following code. When it runs, it logs my three orders but I get a subtotal of 0. It should multiply the orderCount of 3 by 7.5 since I called the function takeOrder three times. Am I missing anything?

```
var orderCount = 0;

function takeOrder(topping, crustType){
    orderCount + 1;
    console.log("Order: " + crustType + " pizza topped with " + topping + ".");
}

function getSubTotal(itemCount) {
    return itemCount * 7.5;
}

takeOrder("mushroom", "stuff crust");

takeOrder("pepperoni", "thin crust");

takeOrder("sausage", "sicilian crust");

console.log(getSubTotal(orderCount));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `orderCount`

```
orderCount += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
orderCount + 1;
```

won't increment the value of `orderCount`.

Use

```
orderCount++;
```

instead, which is short for

```
orderCount += 1;
```

which is short for

```
orderCount = orderCount + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderCount = 0;

function takeOrder(topping, crustType){
    orderCount ++;
    console.log("Order: " + crustType + " pizza topped with " + topping + ".");
}

function getSubTotal(itemCount) {
    return itemCount * 7.5;
}

takeOrder("mushroom", "stuff crust");

takeOrder("pepperoni", "thin crust");

takeOrder("sausage", "sicilian crust");

console.log(getSubTotal(orderCount));
```

> Change orderCount + 1; to orderCount++;